# How to change cursor on mouseup?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to change cursor from garb to grabbing on mouseup.

I tried to add CSS class on mouseup and it is working fine but it is a little problem with this solution.

**Componenet file**

```
<span(mouseup)="status=!status" [ngClass]="status? 'cursorGrabbing' : ''"
class="icon"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.cursorGrabbing{
    cursor:grabbing;
}
```

But the cursor is changing only after I release the mouse button.
It should change curosr immediately when i click and hold the mouse button.
Do you have any idea hot to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both **`(mousedown)`** and **`(mouseup)`** event, and you using the wrong [ngClass syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) convention, it should be:

```
<span (mousedown)="status=true" (mouseup)="status=false" [ngClass]="{'cursorGrabbing' : status}" class="icon"></span>
```

[A working stackbliz example for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwmazj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(mousedown)`event and`(mouseup)` on same element: *It Will register the event when the mouse is clicked down, not needing to wait for the click to release*. So, your code will be

```
<span (mousedown)="status=true" (mouseup)="status=false" [ngClass]="{'cursorGrabbing' : status}"
class="icon"></span>
```

Hope it will work for you...

Comment: Thanks but on mousedown is the same effect. Cursor is changing only if I release click.

Comment: @obaram can you create a case on plunker and share the link with us?

Comment: I think it is sth specific in my project  ( Maybe some pointer events or sth like that. ) because on plunker clear project it is working fine, so iI need to investigate what is wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @obaram Do you got the solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, it`s drag & drop in my project and I have to leave it for now and fix other issues but i let you know.